# Adding a controller in a React dotnet 7 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created my dotnet 7 react application using:

```
dotnet new react -o my-new-app
```

Based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?preserve-view=true&tabs=netcore-cli&view=aspnetcore-7.0

Now, following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

I tried to add my controller called UserInfoController.cs (created within the Controllers folder)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace my-new-app.Controllers;

public class UserInfoController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Default Action for User Controller";
    }

    public string Welcome()
    {
        return "The is the Welcome Action";
    }
}
```

Yet, whenever I run the link that makes the call

```
 https:// ..... /UserInfo
```

I get the response:

```
No routes matched location "/UserInfo"
```

The application is running anyway. I also have:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try https://.../User instead.  If that doesn't work, look at what you have set up for `app.MapControllerRoute`.

Comment: I changed User to UserInfo and still having this problem (please, see updated question). I wonder if there is a problem with the AppRoutes.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the routes to the setupProxy.js in the "clientApp"
For example, I create an api controller to return string with route "/api/values/test"

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public string test()
        {
            return "Successfully call the backend controller";
        }
    }
```

Go to client App open the "setupProxy.js"
[image]
Add `"/api/values/test"` into the "context" Arrary
[image]
Now you could visit the route with no problem.
[image]

You could also proxy the whole "values" controller like this
[image]